# FireFox Download Source

Tags: virus, macos, firefox

While downloading the latest version of Firefox for Mac, i took a peek at the source.  The names don't look legit but i am not that familiar with how CDNs work.

I hit download multiple times and found these sources, which i got from the "from" portion:

http://mozilla.mirros.aarnet.edu.au

http://mirror.metrocast.net

Is this legit?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to but i am wondering if those sources were in fact legit?

Comment: I did some more digging for you, and posted a full answer.  The only thing I didn't cover was exactly how to get a hash of your local copy of the file.  Google should be able to help you with that.

Comment: This isn't a CDN as most people refer to it, it's a mirror network. Other networks have donated bandwidth for free to the project. +1 to Iszi's answer... covers everything else I'd have said.

Answer (score 7):

When I tried downloading from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/fx/ I was pointed to http://mirrors.coreix.net once, then http://mozilla.mirror.nexicom.net/, then http://mozilla.c3sl.ufpr.br.  Whether this is the way Firefox's download page is supposed to work or not, I do not know myself.

A more appropriate way to resolve this though, would be to ask:  "Where can I find official hashes of the Firefox installation files?".  This has been [asked and answered](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/748051#answer-215459) on Mozilla's support forums.

Start [here](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/), and pick the version of Firefox you want.  Then, look for and open a file called MD5SUMS or SHA1SUMS (depending on your preference) in that version's sub-directory.  Within that file are hashes for *all* OS- and language-specific versions of the installer for that edition of Firefox.  Find the name of your installer, and compare the hash to one that you run yourself (using your tool of choice) on the file that you've downloaded.

Even better, from that starting point, you can just navigate to the folder that contains the installer you need and download it straight from Mozilla instead of a mirror.  You should still verify the file hash as described above.

Still, if you're really paranoid about downloading a virus, you may want to consider this:

[Does hashing a file from an unsigned website give a false sense of security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/does-hashing-a-file-from-an-unsigned-website-give-a-false-sense-of-security)